# Pumpkin pie filling way too thick

Tags: pumpkin

I am making pumpkin pie from scratch, the filling is way thicker than in the video recipe I followed. Will it still cook properly?

I used 2 cups of fresh pumpkin, 2 eggs plus one yolk and one cup of buttermilk.

Comment: I'd add a bit of cream or milk is it really is too thick but I'm sure it'll be fine without

Comment: As Doug says, add a little cream or milk. Squash/pumpkin water content varies a *lot*. Fortunately you still get a tasty pie without being too picky about how wet the filling looks.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using canned pumpkin or are you using a fresh pumpkin after roasting it.  I believe you may need to add a half cup more buttermilk or regular milk to your recipe.